# jQuery to match HTML grab product ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Complete novice here in regards to jQuery (I'm learning via CodeCademy). Please excuse any terminology misgivings here.

I have this eCommerce site and I want to match the product ID in GoogleAnalytics using jQuery.

The HTML string I have is:

```
<p class="product-sku">Product Code: <span itemprop="identifier">VVTX101</span></p>
```

Therefore would the jQuery expression in GoogleAnalytics be:

```
$(“itemprop.identifier”)
```

.. and this would retrieve the value of "VVTX101".

Is that right?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Since `itemprop` is an attribute, you can use **[attribute equal selectors](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** along with **[.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)** to get the text of your `span`:

```
$('span[itemprop="identifier"]').text()
```

Your current selector will match an `<itemprop>` element with class `identifier`

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f34C6/)**

Answer (score 0):

go through below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/avmCX/18/

```
alert($('span[itemprop="identifier"]').text());
```

or

```
alert($('span[itemprop="identifier"]').html());
```